# Bottom Right Overlay via CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

The NY Times used to popup an overlay at the bottom right of the screen which would provide a link to similar stories, etc.  I was wondering what the best method for doing this is?  Do you have a hidden div and activate it after a certain amount of time in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delay would work, but most news sites that use this type of interface tie it to the scroll position - when you are near the bottom, the element is displayed.  Use the [window's scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onscroll) to determine when the user is within x% of the bottom of the screen, then animate the div into view.

Really, really basic quick and dirty:

```
window.onscroll = function {
   var D = document;
   var height = Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );

    var pos = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

   if (pos / height > .8)
     document.getElementById('bottom_popover').style.display = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start off with a hidden div, absolutely-positioned:

```
<div class="bottomMsg" stlye="display:none">My stuff!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottomMsg {
   width:100px;  
   bottom:0px;
   right:100px;
   position:absolute; 
}
```

JS: I'm using jQuery here for a nice fade-in effect. The timer uses milliseconds 4000 = 4 sec.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.bottomMsg').fadeIn('slow')  
},4000)
```

Comment: `position:absolute` relates to the page. `position:fixed` relates to the viewport (doesn't scroll out of view).